# flutter: just_audio player plugin seekToNext and seekToPrevious

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter and Im creating a music player using just_audio plugin but I having trouble implementing the nxt button where I want to change the song that currently playing.

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: item.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.data![index].title),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                      onPressed: () {
                        playmusichandler('${item.data![index].uri}');
                      },
                    ),
```

t

```
  void playmusic() async{
  try {
    await widget.audioPlayer
        .setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(widget.songModel.uri!)));
    await widget.audioPlayer.play();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('$e');
  }
}
```

==

```
 StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
        stream: widget.audioPlayer.sequenceStateStream,
        builder: (context, index) {
          return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.audioPlayer.hasNext
                    ? widget.audioPlayer.seekToNext()
                    : null;
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.skip_next,
                size: 45.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ));
        }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that here you are working with audio clips which means you are using single songs. Nevertheless, a playlist is another option available in the **just_audio** package.

[Working with gapless playlists](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#working-with-gapless-playlists:%7E:text=Working%20with%20gapless%20playlists%20%23).

```
`// Define the playlist
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
  // Start loading next item just before reaching it
  useLazyPreparation: true,
  // Customise the shuffle algorithm
  shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
  // Specify the playlist items
  children: [
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track2.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track3.mp3')),
  ],
);

// Load and play the playlist
await player.setAudioSource(playlist, initialIndex: 0, initialPosition: Duration.zero);
await player.seekToNext();                     // Skip to the next item
await player.seekToPrevious();                 // Skip to the previous item
await player.seek(Duration.zero, index: 2);    // Skip to the start of track3.mp3
await player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);        // Set playlist to loop (off|all|one)
await player.setShuffleModeEnabled(true);      // Shuffle playlist order (true|false)

// Update the playlist
await playlist.add(newChild1);
await playlist.insert(3, newChild2);
await playlist.removeAt(3);`
```

When you are dealing with children, you have to pass the audio list to them. Following that, **you can use the index to determine which song will play** when you select a song, then you can choose to play previous or other options